# Append multiple UserControls to WinForm Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, user-controls, panel

I'm trying to append multiple UserControls to my WinForm Panel.

At first, the Controls.Add() function was adding the UserControls one above the other. But then I figured out that I need to use Dock property. I've changed the Dock property of the UserControl to DockStyle.Left and this is what I've got:

[image]

But when I tried to add another UserControl this is what I've got:

[image]

The added UserControl leaked out of the panel.

I want the new UserControl to be appended in the new line if there not enough space for the previous line to contain the UserControl.

I would expect to see something like that:

[image]

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Replace the regular panel with [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @IvanStoev - great! Worked like a charm!

Comment: if it worked, post your solution as a [self answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @IvanStoev I solved the problem.

What I needed to do is to change my Panel to FlowLayoutPanel. 
[FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) arranges himself the appended UserControls.